# How to query two tables in psql to check if data in one table exists in another?

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a psql query where I want to find all the data in row 1 of Table A that don't exist in row 2 of Table B?

Comment: select * from table_a a where not exists (select * from table_b b where b.id = a.id); Voila!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little lost as to what you are asking about, but maybe the PostgreSQL's `EXCEPT [ALL]` operator is what you're looking for, e.g.

```
select column_a, column_b, column_c
from table_A
except all
select column_a, column_b, column_c
from table_B
;
```

[Refer PostgrSQL Documentaion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-union.html)